What does exactly "aurait été" mean
I have learned that "aurait" is the conditionnel of "avoir", equal to "could have" or "would have" in English. So "Tes devoirs auraient été fait" means "your homeworks could have been done", which generally means you could have done your homeworks but you did not.
Today I have read a sentence about Rome: "Une ville qui aurait été fondée au VIIIe siècle avant J.-C. par Romulus", I thought it means "a city that could have been founded in the 8th century by Romulus", but google translates to "a city that is said to have been founded in the 8th century by Romulus" which makes much more sense. But I am confused because these 2 sentences are very different.
How comes "aurait été" is translated to "is said to have been"?

To make more sense of it, you could think of it as reading "A city that might have been founded in the 8th century B.C. by Romulus (but wasn't)", which is similar to "Your homework could have been done (but wasn't)."

I think this aurait été has become more or less "code" for is said to have been in cases like this about events in the past.

@Frank even for is said by some and was said to have been: because On dit que Rome a été fondée (w/out conditionnel) is possible, too.

@FrançoisJurain Certes, il y a des variations, mais un conditionnel tout seul (sans le on dit) dans le passé a souvent ce sens de "on dit", je trouve.

Would have and could have are pretty different. "Tes devoirs auraient été fait" means "Your homework would have been done", not could. Note that it doesn't mean much on its own, you need to add some context, like

Si tu avais commencé plus tôt, tes devoirs auraient été faits (maintenant)


If you had started earlier, your homework would have been done (by now)

In your example about Rome, literally it means "A city that would have been built in the 7th century", but in French that tense is used to talk about uncertainty, unverified information, similarly to "alleged" in English, or "said to", as mentioned in comments.

Le PDG, qui aurait détourné des millions de dollars, sera jugé aujourd'hui.


The CEO, who allegedly embezzled millions of dollars, will be tried today.


je pense qu'on appelle ça le "conditionnel journalistique" quand on parle d'un information non certaine. Souvent complété de "d'après ..." ou "selon ...", mais pas toujours !

Oui, en anglais said to be x ou allegedly ou apparently.

@Teleporting Goat Thanks for the explanation. You are right, would and could are different. It's not my native language therefore I use in a very unprecise way.
It's first time I learn that "aurait" could imply "alleged" or "said to", that does help a lot. Thanks a lot

@fasligand Thanks. Feel free to accept the answer if it answered your question :)
